# get ldap attribute PwdLastSet using java

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to retrieve the PwdLastSet attribute from LDAP using java.  It fails and doesn't throw an error.  Here's the code:

```
    private String getPasswordLastSet() {
        int searchScope = LDAPConnection.SCOPE_BASE;
        int ldapVersion  = LDAPConnection.LDAP_V3;
        int ldapPort = 389;
        String ldapHost = "Adapps.domain.mycompany.com";
        String loginDN  = "cn=myNTusername,OU=users,OU=colorado,OU=corporate,dc=domain,dc=mycompany,dc=com";
        String password = "myNTpassword";
        String baseDn = "dc=mycompany,dc=com";

        LDAPConnection lc = new LDAPConnection();

        String attributes[] = {"PwdLastSet"};
        String pwdLastSet = null;

        try {
            lc.connect( ldapHost, ldapPort );
            lc.bind( ldapVersion, loginDN, password.getBytes("UTF8") );
            String filter = "(sAMAccountName=myNtusername)";
            LDAPSearchResults searchResults =
                    lc.search(  baseDn,
                                searchScope,
                                filter,
                                attributes,         
                                true);       // return attributes and values

            while ( searchResults.hasMore()) {
                LDAPEntry nextEntry = null;                 
                try {
                    actionlogger.debug("about to searchResults.next...");
                    nextEntry = searchResults.next();
                    actionlogger.debug("about to nextEntry.getAttribute...");
                    LDAPAttribute pwdLastSetAttribute = nextEntry.getAttribute("PwdLastSet");
                    pwdLastSet = pwdLastSetAttribute.getStringValue();
                } catch(LDAPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch( LDAPException e ) {
            actionlogger.error( "Error occured while LDAP Search : " +  e.getMessage(),e );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pwdLastSet;
    }
```

The output is

> about to searchResults.next...

But

> about to nextEntry.getAttribute...

is never hit.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which Java LDAP API are you using? You should check that you received an LDAPEntry at nextEntry?  Log the DN of the entry so you know which Entry. Also, are you sure there is a pwdLastSet value on the entry?

Comment: com.novell.ldap - Yes, I know there is a PwdLastSet attribute because I can run ldapSearch from linux command line and can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nearly correct.  I just

1. Changed searchScope to LDAPConnection.SCOPE_SUB;
2. Changed loginDN = DOMAIN\MyNTusername;
3. Changed baseDN = "dc=mydomain,dc=mycompany,dc=com";
4. Changed true to false in lc.search.

Not sure which of those changes caused it to start working.